# How to render the same component with different props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I'm learning react recently. 
I want to render a component with different props again but it doesn't work.

Here is the js code

```
// page container
class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.type);
        this.state = {
            type: this.props.type
        }
    } // end of constructor

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.type}>
            </div>
        );
    } // end of render()

} // end of componenet: page container

function show() {
    ReactDOM.render(<Page type="page1"/>, $("#main")[0]);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page type="homepage" />, $("#main")[0]);
```

the html includes a button which will call the show() when clicked. 
How to make it render again when I click on the button

Comment: *when I click on the button* - which button? You likely need to encapsulate all things that are related to React app inside of it, including that button.

Comment: just a button inside the html body
like this
<button onclick="show()"> click </button>

Comment: Is there a reason why it's not inside React app? In case there is, consider updating the question with your case explained in detail. The thing you're trying to do would be ok in jQuery but React is not jQuery and shouldn't be treated like one.

Comment: here is my html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" 
crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" 
crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <button onclick="show()"> click </button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: `<button onclick="show()"> click </button>` should be placed inside `Page`. Then you can update component state. Simple as that.

Comment: like this inside Page?
render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.type}>
                <div className="icon">
                </div>
                <button onClick={show}>click</button>
                <NavBar type={this.state.type} />
            </div>
        );
    } // end of render()

Comment: stil not working

Comment: I've tried to explain that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

React state isn't supposed to be modified from the outside. In this case there are no reasons to place a button outside React application. When it's place inside, it can update the state:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    this.state = {
        type: 'homepage'
    };

    render() {
        return <>
            <div className={this.state.type}></div>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ type: 'page1' })}>click</button>
        <>;
    } 

}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, $("#main")[0]);
```